# Can we uniquely identify request to send respond from a POST method?

Tags: java, python, rest, jax-rs, flask-restful

I am working on a web-service which is asynchronous. In my client code, I am using a `boto3 session client` to call a GET API of my Jetty Server which is S3 alike service. GET API fetched original data from S3 and modifies the request so as to be able to forward the request to flask server. Python flask then get the request processed (where data transformation is done) and calls the POST API of the Jetty Server.

Now I am stuck at figuring out how can I respond to the original caller? Because I am not sure if a API request can have a session-id to identify the original caller?

How can my POST API respond back to client? Following is the overall conceptualization of what I am trying to achieve. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: I don't get why you would trigger a POST request from a GET request. This itself looks like bad design, but I also don't get what that POST request is even required to do? Why would that Flask Server create their own request instead of responding to the initial request from the Jetty Server?

Comment: @Tom I need to make this work asynchronously because, I am trying to recreate my own service of S3 object lambda. The lambda function with Flask Server transforms the data and then calls the POST api of my Jetty server. This POST API is writeGetObjectResponse() which then need to respond to the original request from client. I am trying to reproduce the AWS service but in my own environment. Please let me know if I need to make this more clear.

Comment: HTTP requests are not asynchronous.  The original GET request has to block until you have a response ready to send.  You can't defer it and finish it later.  It's going to wait for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I think I now understand that part. But I am confused on the part that how would I send response to original GET request from writeGetObjectResponse()? Is there a request identifier mechanisms through which API will know where to respond back? Or I am looking at it totally wrong?

Comment: Well, your diagram is confusing, because the names don't match your description.  Where's Flask?  Where's Jetty?  What's HS or HSC?  Are you actually calling lambdas, or are you just providing services that feel like lambdas?

Comment: Think about it this way.  If the original client request is handled by your Flask app, then you'll receive the request in a Python function.  That function eventually has to return a string.  That is its purpose in life.  You have to figure out how to construct that string.  You can call whatever external services you need to to create that string.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just updated the diagram. For more simplification - my java server  behaves like a lambda server that gets actual object, gets lambda function name from redis and then forwards the request to Flask to execute lambda functions  transformation. Then it should get the modified object but in a API called writeGetObjectResponse(). I am not sure if this is a case of async wait or something? Does this make it more clear?

Comment: Only slightly.  I don't understand why "GET API" and "POST API" are separate.  The "GET API" is the one that has to respond to the client.  It can certainly formulate a request to your Flask back end, wait for the response, then forward it back to the original GET request, but it's never going to be a POST request.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am reproducing the way AWS does it. Basically, I am trying to write my own API for this. In AWS, GET getObject() is responded by POST writeGetObjectResponse(). https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.java#L6451

Comment: No.  GET and POST are both request.  They are incoming  `writeGetObjectReponse` responds to that original GET request.  There's no POST involved.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not much experienced with it but with all due respect, when I see the request syntax on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_WriteGetObjectResponse.html for `writeGetObjectResponse` I see its a POST request. Am I missing something that you mentioned in your last comment?

Comment: Yes, you are confusing the players here.  Check this diagram.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transforming-objects.html  The client does a get request.  Inside S3, there may be many GET and POST requests between various components, but when that's all done, you'll respond to the original GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using embedded Jetty, I used the built-in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.Listener`.

I now have access to the raw internal Jetty `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` object that has the HTTP Fields for that request.

To use it, I'll create an instance of that `HttpChannel.Listener`, and add it as a bean to my connectors.

```java
public class RequestChannelListener implements HttpChannel.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onRequestBegin(Request request) {
        HttpFields.Mutable replacement = HttpFields.build(request.getHttpFields())
                .put("X-Request-ID", UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase());
        request.setHttpFields(replacement);
    }
}
```

Add as a bean in the connector -

```java
RequestChannelListener channelListener = new RequestChannelListener();
connector.addBean(channelListener);
```

Then all other access of that request, be it internal components of Jetty, a webapp, a specific servlet, filters, forwarding, includes, error handling in the servlet spec, error handling outside of a servlet context, etc can all see it.

To check if the custom header got added into the request or not -

```java
Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Header Name - " + headerName + ", Value - " + request.getHeader(headerName));
        }
```